# JavaScript API for Office getFileAsync Function is not calling callback

Tags: javascript, office365, office365-apps, office365api, javascript-api-for-office

I've developed a very simple taskPane add-in that I'd like to test in Excel Online. I used Visual Studio 2015 and Javascript Api for Office, and I started a new project Office/Sharepoint --> Then I selected the Task Pane option. 
The only thing I changed to the sample they build is in Home.js :

```js
/// <reference path="../App.js" />

(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            app.initialize();

            $('#get-crazy').click(getCrazy);
        });
    };

    // Reads data from current document selection and displays a notification
    function getCrazy(){
        Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, {sliceSize: 2097152},
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                    console.log("I'm here :D ");
                } else {
                    app.showNotification('Error:', result.error.message);
                }
            }
        );
    }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="../../Content/Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- To enable offline debugging using a local reference to Office.js, use:                        -->
    <!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
    <!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/1.1/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->

    <link href="../App.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content-header">
        <div class="padding">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-main">
        <div class="padding">
            <button id="get-crazy"> SURPRISE! </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also changed the manifest so its startAction points out to InternetExplorer and I'm using a sharePoint Developer site to open this Excel Online.
When I run the code I get this messages:

```
XML5619: Incorrect document syntax.
Line: 1, Column 1
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/http_500.htm
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTemplate.css
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/info_48.png
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/down.png
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/down.png
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient.jpg
```

And when I press the button I only have this: Agave.HostCall.IssueCall. And I know it's 'stuck' in the getFileAsync function.. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a local copy of Excel, rather than Excel online, just to see if this is the problem?

Comment: Well, this function hasn't support towards Excel Desktop, I have tried it using a local Copy of Word and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You should use office.js version 1.1, as getFileAsync() just supported by 1.1, so you shoud replace the "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" by "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js".

Comment: Thanks @shanbo. I've already tried to do so and it didn't work.

Comment: The code seems ok except the first line "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
", this line should be deleted, and another issue is you should call closeAsync() to release the getFileAsync call result, for detail, please refer to msdn. But the issue seems not be caused by it, do you mind publishing you whole VS project in Github and share the URL to me? so I can debug it in my local machine. By the way, I have paste your home.html and home.js code and test it on agave, everything is ok.

Comment: @PastelBelem, the URL have no content. Do you forget adding code or the URL is no right?

Comment: I'm so sorry @shanbo. I'm kind'a new to this gitHub thing and I'm on windows, which makes it a bit different. I don't want to take you much longer so I'm sharing this [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6cpgvfv53tthzxe/AAC0uoX9TXhSqrkwpQB1BtVCa?dl=0) link which has the project's zip.

Comment: @PastelBelem, i have tested your agave on onedrive, it is ok. so do your run it on Sharepoint online? currently, we do not enable the getFileAsync() on Sharepoint online, you can try this API on onedrive (https://onedrive.live.com).

Comment: how did you test it in one.drive? I'm having this error when deploying from VS15:   Error occurred in deployment step "Uninstall app for SharePoint': The remote server returned and error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: you should first install your agave on onedrive envrionment, but this is something difficult than in sharepoint online. Another way is you can just insert a avaliable agave(for example, wikipedia) in onedrive, then using Fiddler to redirect the url to your agave url. By the way, if you just want to try to use agave in  sharepoint online, then you can use other api(for example, getSelectedDataAsync() ) in your agave.

Comment: the thing is, I don't want just the selected data but the whole document, you know?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a silly question but what exactly is an Agave? I know this app I have is an agave, but I can't seem to find any definition relating to it. How exactly would I insert the wikipedia agave in One Drive?